# Water Material Not Working the Same in Eevee as it Does in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, eevee-render-engine, reflection

I am working on a scene where the water needs to be somewhat transparent and reflective (like water generally is). It looks great in Cycles, but when I switch to Eevee, it does not look the same or even close to what I'm going for. Screen Space Reflections is on (with refraction). The closest I could get was switching the Blend Mode to Alpha Hashed in Eevee, but it still isn't right. Is this a limitation of Eevee or am I missing something?

I've attached screenshots of Cycles vs. Eevee.

[image: Cycles]
[image: Eevee]

Answer (score 1):

Eevee works differently than cycles and does not have all the same capabilities. You can try compositing cycles and eevee renders for different parts of your scene using the Holdout shader, but because the water has those reflections, you might just have to do the whole thing in Cycles.